# Results of @view in an array?

Tags: julia

I have a 121x2 matrix named AgeValues, which has Age in column 1 and a corresponding age value in column 2.  I'm using @view to create a subset of AgeValues for each age in a 165-element data set.

```
AgeValues = Matrix(AgeValues)
function AgeValuesX(i) 
    @view AgeValues[i+1:end,2]
end

Values_ageX = AgeValuesX.(age)
```

This is returning the data I need, but in a 165x1 vector (with the results comma delimited in each row of the vector).  I'm trying to convert this into a 165x121 array.

My problem is that each of the elements are of a different length.  I've tried reduce(vcat()):

```
reduce(vcat, transpose(Values_ageX))
ERROR: ArgumentError: number of columns of each array must match (got (29, 42))
```

I've tried reshape:

```
reshape(Values_ageX, 165, 121)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("new dimensions (165, 121) must be consistent with array size 165")
```

I've tried resizing the @view:

```
AgeValues = Array(AgeValues)
function AgeValuesX(i) 
    resize!(@view AgeValues[i+1:end,2],121)
end
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Invalid use of @view macro: argument must be a reference expression A[...]
```

Any suggestions?  I need this to be an array, so I can use the exp.() function on the results - this doesn't seem to work on my 165x1 vector (`ERROR: MethodError: no method matching exp(::SubArray{Float64, 1, Matrix{Float64}, Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}, Int64}, true})`) - I need to take the exp of each value in each element. Thank you!

EDIT to add more info:
AgeValues is a DataFrame read from a CSV file before I convert it to a matrix.  Even if I don't convert it to a matrix, once I use the function, it outputs a vector.

The first few lines of Values_AgeX looks like this:

```
165-element Vector{SubArray{Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}}, true}}:
 [0.228571429, 0.2, 0.171428571, 0.142857143, 0.114285714, 0.085714286, 0.057142857, 0.028571429, 0.0, 0.0  …  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
 [0.6, 0.571428571, 0.542857143, 0.514285714, 0.485714286, 0.457142857, 0.428571429, 0.4, 0.371428571, 0.342857143  …  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The number of values in each element is 121 less `age`. I want to be able to `resize!` each row to 121 (padding with zeros, which `resize!` will do for me), which will give me the 165x121 matrix.

My end goal is for this vector to be output as an array so I can multiply each value by another value in another 165x121 array.

Comment: The fundamental issue here is.. what are you trying to do? There isn't enough values here; 165*121 > 165*1. Are you trying to create a sparse matrix? If so, where do you want these values to end up? Along the diagonal? 

Also, making why would making this into a 165*121 matrix make any difference for `exp`? Also, also, the error message indicates that you did `exp(x)` not `exp.(x)`

Comment: Thanks, you’re right on the exp vs exp. but still doesn’t work. Basically, I have 165 different data points with different ages and I’m trying to create a survival curve for each of those ages. Survival curves run from 0 to 121, hence the 165*121. If it’s a matrix and the elements are separated, then broadcasting the operator works (I’ve tested it on another part of the calculation), but because I have one vector with varying numbers of values in each row, I can’t perform operations on each value in the row. If it was a 165*121, I could do that.

Comment: Also, it can be an array instead of a matrix, but I get the same results and errors when my first line of code is AgeValues = Array(AgeValues). AgeValues runs from age 0 to 120, and What I’m after here is an array, containing the subset of those values from age x to 120. If I can output these into an array, I can resize them to be 121 for later multiplication with another 165*121 array. Does that help?

Comment: matrices are (2d) arrays. They make absolutely no difference for broadcasting elementwise operations.  You don't reveal what "AgeValues" was before you reconstructed it as a Matrix, so noone can help with that.

Unfortunately, you are still not explaining at all how you expect the 165 values to be assembled into the 19965 possible positions of the much much larger 165 by 121 matrix.

Comment: I've edited the post to add more detail.  I've been learning Julia for about 2 weeks, so still fairly new to this.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still unsure exactly what you want. I assume that the variable `age` is a vector with 165 elements? You don't state this, forcing everyone to guess.

One should always start questions with a complete, small, example and the desired output:

```
agevalues = [0 0.9;
             1 0.8;
             2 0.7;
             3 0.6]

# I can only assume this contains duplicate values since it's supposed to be longer:
ages = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]

# Desired output???
agematrix = [0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6;
             0.8 0.7 0.6 0.0;
             0.7 0.6 0.0 0.0;
             0.7 0.6 0.0 0.0;
             0.8 0.7 0.6 0.0;
             0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0]
```

The @view macro replaces what would have been a (potentially) costly *copy* of the data with a indirect view onto the same data where changing the layout doesn't make any sense (I incorrectly claimed it was read only, but i was of course wrong; you could modify the contents they view if desired).
Secondly, resize! will not even initialize the data; so there won't be any zero padding, so we can't use it since we can't modify a view, but we also don't even want uninitialized data. You wanted zeros.

A good general strategy for loops and broadcasts is to only think of the **single** case first:

- *What do we want from a single `age` value?*

Well, the sliced vector, **padded with extra zeros**.
With minimal modifications to your code, we pad it with zeros:

```
function AgeValuesX(i) 
    vcat((@view AgeValues[i+1:end,2]), zeros(i))
end
```

this creates a new array that matches a single line of our final data.
The rest of your code simply just works now.

(There are faster ways to achieve this, avoiding extra allocations, by simply assembling into a pre-allocated 165x121 matrix directly.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.  You're right on the age vector, and your output is exactly what I'm after.  I've modified my function to include the vcat but I get the following error: `ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Invalid use of @view macro: argument must be a reference expression A[...].`.  When you say assemble into a pre-allocated matrix, how would I do this?

Comment: I missed the parenthesis

Comment: I've got it using CatViews.jl and reduce(vcat(transpose())). Will edit the original question - thank you for your help, the vcat was the bit I was missing! EDIT - Your way works too!! Thank you so much, I do appreciate it - and will make sure I include more information in my questions in future!!

Comment: Views are not read-only. You can certainly modify their contents.

Comment: @phipsgabler ah yes you are right. My mental model just didn't allow me to think of them as such since i was so focused on modifying the layout which doesn't make any sense here.